# How to get the full path of a directory given only the name of the directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a pydev project where for some reason I consider a web application.
I have the path of one file of the web application project. say I have -

```
C:\webflow_implementaton\SpringWebFlowFlightBooking-master\src\main\java\it\iol\springwebflow\Booking.java
```

With this information can I fetch the path where the "webapp" folder is located in the web application? Is it possible in python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe... give us some extra information. I understand that path would be the input. Which would be the output?

Comment: I want the path of "webapp" folder to be the output, for the above example, I want something like "C:\webflow_implementaton\SpringWebFlowFlightBooking-master\src\main\webapp"  as the output

Comment: Is "C:\webflow_implementaton\SpringWebFlowFlightBooking-master\src\main\" always going to be the same? or do you need to approach it by searching all folders in a path for the webapp folder using the java file you specified as input?

Comment: As @Poshi has pointed out, the question seems to be vague. Some more information is needed for anyone to help you out.

Comment: @Ciaran The second part of your question is what I am looking for..using the path of the java file (which is a part of the web application), I need to find the path of the webapp folder

Comment: Sorry @shweta, but I don't get which transformation are you performing for going from "C:\webflow_implementaton\SpringWebFlowFlightBooking-master\src\main\java\it\iol\springwebflow\Booking.java" to "C:\webflow_implementaton\SpringWebFlowFlightBooking-master\src\main\webapp". You need to remove from the first "java" appearance and add webapp in its place?

Comment: BTW, you want "something like"??? If you don't know exactly what you expect, it will be impossible for us to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Sorry, my question is - Is it possible to get the path of a particular folder( in my case, webapp), when the path of a file in the same source application is given??

Comment: All the data I get is  -  C:\webflow_implementaton\SpringWebFlowFlightBooking-master\src\main\java\it\iol\springwebflow\Booking.java" , i need to trace back and try to fetch the path where the web app is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would os.walk work for your case? Very rough example written below, im sure there is a quicker way to do it.

It takes your path, splits it such that you can go back to a default folder level of your choice. Then uses os.walk to go through all folders until it finds webapp.

```
import os

path = 'C:\\webflow_implementaton\\SpringWebFlowFlightBooking-master\\
        src\\main\\java\\it\\iol\\springwebflow\\Booking.java'

path_split = path.split("\\")[::-1]

#default folder depth to use
folders_deep = 1

for i in path_split[0:folders_deep]:
    path = path.replace("\\"+i,"")
print (path)

list_dir = os.walk(path)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        if "webapp" in name: 
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
        else:
            print("Folder not found")
```

Comment: Did that answer your question? Let me know, im sure it can be modified to you needs.

Comment: Sorry for late reply...I tried your approach and it works just perfect:)